# WPF AvalonEdit insert text in position

Tags: c#, wpf, document, caret, avalonedit

I'm writing my engineering work.
I have a problem with Avalon Edit control.
I want to add some text on button clicked at cursor position. But i cannot do it, I have tried everything i found.
I can't get even CaretOffset from avalonEdit.

```
 <avalonEdit:TextEditor
                            Document="{Binding Dokument, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                            IsModified="{Binding Path=Edited, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
                            ShowLineNumbers="True" 
                            SyntaxHighlighting="XML"
                            >
```

How can I paste my text at cursor position in other way?
Many thanks for any help or just tips ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Could be wrong; all untested.

I believe you need to gain access to your `TextDocument` instance. There should be an `Insert(int offset, string text)` method according to the code on GitHub:
https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/master/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Document/TextDocument.cs

In order to get the offset, you will need to get access to the TextEditor instance. There you will find the `CaretOffset` property. That should tell you location of the caret and be what you pass into the `Insert` method.
https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/master/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/TextEditor.cs

I'd give an example and test it, but I no longer have access to that code and leaving work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Document property of the editor instance and use its Insert method.

```
 public void Insert(int startIdx, string text)
 {
     _avalonTextEditor.Document.Insert(startIdx, text);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public void InsertTextCurrentPosition(string text)
{
    int caretOffset = _avalonTextEditor.CaretOffset;
    _avalonTextEditor.Document.Insert(caretOffset, text);
}
```